# Let be $T \in L (V) $ a nilpotent operator, $T^{ p }= 0.$ Show that the I-T operator is invertible

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I need some help with this exercise, I did the version with matrices but I don't know how to extrapolate it to linear operators, a hint is enough for me

Answer (score 2):

$(I-T)(I+T+T^2+...+T^{p-1})=I-T^p=I$. So $(I-T)^{-1}=I+T+T^2+...+T^{p-1}$.